# JSON hosted on Google Drive is not parsed

Tags: objective-c, json

I'm trying to parse a json file hosted on my Google Drive. I'm using the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3CRs9y562F3a0VXTXNaekNiSXM/edit?usp=sharing"];

    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSDictionary* jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
            NSLog(@"jsonDictionary \n%@", jsonDictionary);
        }
    }];


}
```

I checked the url, and figure it's either the code, or no access from Google Drive. If the code is bad, I can't see where it is. If the .json file cannot be parsed from Google Drive, where can I host an have access to this content? Must it be on my own domain? I looked in to hosting on Google Code, but definitely does not look like what I need with version control, and all.

Comment: Seriously, this: "I'm trying to parse a json file hosted on my Google Drive." makes no sense at all. What you do with an HTTP GET request is obtaining data from the server. You specify what kind of data you expect in the "Accept" header, e.g. "Accept: application/json". First and foremost however, you need to ensure the API supports that request at all. When you received the response, check the status code and the response headers if they match your expectation (status code 200 OK, and "Content-Type: application/json"). Then you can process the data in any way you want.

Comment: @CD, you're absolutely correct. It wasn't possible to access .json, and it wasn't possible to parse .txt in GD. It took less time to create an über simple API than time spent pretending such rules did not apply.

Comment: Of course, if that resource is just "text" - as opposed to some structured data - and actually is a text document containing JSON, you would specify "Accept: text/plain; charset=utf-8".  "application/json" is used for a resource which for example exists as a "Model" in some database. If you request "application/json" you effectively instruct the server to create a JSON document which represents this model and pass it over to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I load that url, i'm not really getting anything. another options might be to put the doc behind a node.js api and make rest calls from there, or back it against AWS S3 and make a call from there. I don't think google drive allows for parsing in place except for downloading all the text first. I think hosting it on a service such as heroku with an api will serve you best.

Comment: it was initially a .txt file (you can read that one without downloading), it didn't work, so I tried with .json

Had not noticed the file must be downloaded, but I guess what you're saying above is irrespective, and the most likely solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
your json file format is not proper. Try this code you will get error what is wrong in 
 your json File

NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3CRs9y562F3a0VXTXNaekNiSXM/edit?usp=sharing"];

    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                             returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
    NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response
                                                              options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
    if (!jsonArray) {
                        NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", [jsonParsingError description]);
                    } else {
                        for(NSDictionary *item in jsonArray) {
                            NSLog(@"Item: %@", item);
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: I had tried with NSArray as you have above, with a txt and then with the json url above. It seems parsing from Google Docs is not a possibility, and had to host on barebones api. Also, was trying to stay with asynchronicity.

Comment: +1, great call on the JSON, indeed, it was not validated. Cheers!

Comment: Never load URL Request synchronously in NSURLConnection if its on main thread. It will block the UI. Instead use sendAsynchronousRequest: like OP has used or put the synchronous URLConnection request on a background thread.