# Accessing google drive as JSON via jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, google-drive-api

I'm trying to use Google drive as a testbed for hosting JSON files. This allows me to hand off my client-side files to my designer colleague without the hassle of setting up a WebApi controller or nodeJS server.

I try to call it like this in my JavaScript:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-6bXDnuW6gPT3NUQ1VSQW12Z1k/view?usp=sharing"
    })
  .done(function( data ) {
    // reference data here
    alert( data );
  });
```

And this is the data I'm trying to get back:

```
[{
            "Name": "Soren Kierkegaard",
            "Timestamp": "1301190400",
            "Comment": "Life is understood backwards, but it is lived forwards.",
            "StaticURL": "./img/some_guy2.png"
        }]
```

But I get back:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-6bXDnuW6gPT3NUQ1VSQW12Z1k/view?usp=sharing.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

This inclines me to suspect the browser (or perhaps jQuery?) wants the response header to contain an 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' key/value pair.

Unless I can add this as a key/value pair in the JSON? This would add an outer layer to my data, but I should be able to parse through that OK in the client side JavaScript I guess.

I've tried several combinations of GET/POST and data types. Jsonp seems to suggest I have to have a script set up at Google, and I don't see an easy way to set up jsonp at Google or to ask Google to add something into their response headers.

Similar StackExchange post via different platform and different results: [JSON not parsed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17376699/json-hosted-on-google-drive-is-not-parsed)

Comment: You can't do this because of the AJAX same-origin policy.

Comment: If you want to access Drive files programmatically, you need to use the Drive API. It's not as simple as using the same URL as the Drive web app. See https://developers.google.com/drive/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get around this by using myjson.com as a host provider.

I honestly don't understand how static json files create a security hazard. Dynamic json -maybe- but if it's originating from a file on google Drive it isn't going to be dynamically created, right?

The Google Drive API requires encumbering credential hoops to jump through ... which isn't conducive to rapid prototyping or setting up a staging environment.

Answer (score 0):

From google drive to get the file content you need to change the URL, use googledrive/host link as shown below:
Use link as "https://googledrive.com/host/0B-6bXDnuW6gPT3NUQ1VSQW12Z1k"